# log4j and weblogic: duplicate log messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic

I use log4j for logging in my project. Here is it's sample setup:

```
public class MyClass {
  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public MyClass() {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).setLevel(Level.INFO);
  }

  ...

}
```

The problem is that on each next logger call it duplicates log messages (I mean on first call there is only 1 message, on second call there are 2 same messages, then there are 3 of them and so on). It seems that each time new logger's instance is created and used with all old instances.
How to avoid this problem?
Thanks.

UPP. Tried to make it static,but it doesn't work anyway. I still get multiple log messages. Any ideas? Probably some Weblogic specific stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the logger `static`

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

The key here is to create a `Logger` for each class, and not for each instance.

Comment: Hmm,tried this,but did not succeed.And that's really strange cause your advice look very reasonable.Any other ideas?What can cause the problem?Probably some Weblogic specific stuff?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I have the same behavior here and could not fix this so far.

Answer (score 3):

try setting additivity `false` [programmatically](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setAdditivity%28boolean%29) or in config.

```
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).setAdditivity(false);
```

To me, that did the trick when I set it in *log4j.xml*

```
<logger name="com.stackoverflow.answers.gnat" additivity="false">
    <!-- note additivity value set above -->
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="knowledge"/>
    <appender-ref ref="reputation"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gnat but now I'm getting exception: `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly` No logger at all seems to be initialized.

Comment: _WARN No appenders..._ I see. Sounds familiar. Never was able to pinpoint the reason of that (did I wrote that I hate log4j documentation? only maven docs seems to be worse than it) but it always felt like it happens when I set some attribute too early. Consider trying to set additivity as late as possible. Btw `xml` example in my reply is copied from codebase I work with right now (I just obfuscated company-specific name and refs) and it is proven to work just fine for last half year or something

Answer (score 1):

If you make your Logger class static as suggested above, and then ensure that you're configuring log4j either via a -D system property at the JVM level or in the configuration of your application, you shouldn't have any issues. That call to parse configuration either at class load time or at instance creation time is unnecessary overhead.

log4j should only need to initialise configuration once - whether that's at the initialisation of the server, or at deployment of your application.

Is your project a web application?

Also, you can find out more about hooking into WebLogic Server's logging configuration here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/logging/logging_services.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Pleasure, @kardanov - if you found the answer useful, it would be great if you could vote the answer up. Hope logging is treating you better now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the `BasicConfurator.configure()` method.
I had the exact same issue in my java project, and I'm not using WebLogic.

I moved my `BasicConfigurator.configure()` method from my `beforeTest()` to `beforeClass()`, and suddenly the issue went away.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  GeoLogger.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
}

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
  //BasicConfigurator.configure();
}
```

Hope that helps direct you to a solution.